This Fourier series periodic function will generate zero, what's wrong?
Here is code.
ClearAll[T, A, f, t]; 
f[t_, T_, A_] := Piecewise[{{0, 0 <= t < T/2}, {A, T/2 <= t < T}}] 
r = FourierSeries[f[t, T, A], t, 3, FourierParameters -> {1, 2*Pi/T},    Assumptions -> 0 < T] 
FullSimplify[r] 
ExpToTrig[r]

This output 0. Apparently , it's not 0.

Fix
You can fix this by using:
ClearAll[T, A, f, t]; 
f[t_, T_, A_] := Piecewise[{{0, 0 <= t < T/2}, {A, T/2 <= t < T}}] ;
r = FourierSeries[f[t + T / 2, T, A], t, 3, FourierParameters -> {1, 2*Pi/T}, Assumptions -> 0 < T] /. t -> t - T / 2;
FullSimplify[r] 
ExpToTrig[r]


A plot to check the result (for $T = 2 \cdot \pi \wedge A = 1$ and the upper and lower bound of the sum $= 20$):


Explanation
$f\left( t,\, T,\, A \right)$ is only defined for $t \in \left[ 0,\, T \right]$ and $f\left( t,\, T,\, A \right) = 0 \wedge t \leq \frac{T}{2}$. In the documentation of FourierSeries > Details > FourierParameters we can see that for determining the coefficients the integral in $[-\frac{T}{2},\frac{T}{2}]$ taken, but all defined values ​​for $t \in \left[-\frac{T}{2},\, \frac{T}{2} \right]$ are equal to $0$ and $\int_{a}^{b} 0\, \operatorname{d}t = 0$, so Mathematica gives the answer $0$. At least that's how I would explain it. If that's correct, we could fix this via changing $t$ to $t + \frac{T}{2}$ in the argument (and backshifting $t \to t - \frac{T}{2}$ afterwards) and that seems to work.

As nice as the solution looks, unfortunately it gives a wrong result! Try Plot[{f[t, 2 π, 1], r /. {T -> 2 π, A -> 1}}, {t, 0, 2 π},    Exclusions -> None]

@rmw You're right. My code would calculate the Fourier series coefficients of $f(t+T/2,T,A)$ instead of $f(t,T,A)$. I should have checked it beforehand. I corrected it (by replacing $t$ with $t-T/2$ in $r$).

The range for t is 0 < t < T. Mathematica calculates the Fourier series in the range -Pi < t < Pi. Therefore, the range for t must be scaled accordingly.
{shift, shiftback} = {Rescale[t, {-π, π}, {0, T}], Rescale[t, {0, T}, {-π, π}]};
FourierTrigSeries[f[t, T, A] /. t -> shift, t, 3] /. t -> shiftback //Simplify[#, T > 0] & // Expand

   A/2 - (2 A Sin[(2 π t)/T])/π - (2 A Sin[(6 π t)/T])/(3 π)

